# Treat different static files with nginx in a concrete directory

Tags: nginx

I'm building an application where some files will be served by the app itself. I'm not good on configuring server side things, so my nginx configuration looks like this:

```
location ~* (.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    try_files $uri $1.$3;
}

location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|txt)$ {
    access_log  off;
    expires     30d;
    root        /var/www/domain_tld/public;
}
```

I know that the second rule is for serving the extensions listed directed from nginx and that's cool, but I would like to have a rule that says:

`/data/photos/{string}/{name}.{extension}`

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is not working? What would you like to occur?

Comment: @MichaelHampton actually is giving me a 404, because I think it's trying to find the file and serve without hitting the app. I'm trying with a ".jpg" file so probably is why is hitting the second "location". I would like to be routed (only when it's /data/photos/...) to the app.

Comment: What is the location block for the app?

Answer (score 0):

I make the assumption you wish to server a location URI like `(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$` to a file following `/data/photos/$1/$2.$3`.

Then, it is as simple as that (note that I slightly modified the regex, it might be perfectible to white-list all the cases as close as possible):

```
location ~* ^/(?<string>.+)\.(?<name>\d+)\.(?<extension>js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    root /data/photos;
    try_files $string/$name.$extension =404;
}
```

A call to the `/myString.file.ext` URI will serve content from `/data/photos/myString/file.ext`

Note that all nginx locations start with `/`.

Also remember that each request is served by **only one** location, thus you might want to merge both yours if they are supposed to apply simultaneously to the requests.